# Does CSS3 offer a "minimum-size" property for "background"?

Tags: css, background

I'm using

```
background-size: 100%;
```

To fit my background image (in the body-tag) to the browser window.

But is there a CSS3 background-property to set a minimum-size?

Or will I need some div-"trick" like:

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>

#bg {
    position:fixed;
    top:-50%;
    left:-50%;
    width:200%;
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

Comment: What minimum size are you referring to?

Comment: Minimum the real size of the image...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
background-size: contain;
```

OR

```
background-size: cover;
```

The difference being that `cover` specifies that the background image should be as small as possible while maintaining its aspect ratio. `contain` on the other hand specifies that the background image should be as large as possible.

See the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size).

Comment: It's like they are both doing the same as 100%; I should need the contain, but doens't work well... My code:
`body, html {
 background: url('files/background3.jpg') center 0 fixed;
 background-color: #000;
 font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.3;
 background-size: contain;
}`

Comment: This is not the same as a minimum background size. If I have a 1920 background image, it will not fill a retina screen on full resolution. So you use `contain` for that purpose. But then when you shrink the window size, the background image shrinks with it. I want the image to stretch to fill the screen ONLY when the viewport size exceeds the width of the image, else just use the width of the image. a "min-background-size" property with "auto" to match the size of the background image would be need.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px){
    #bg img { width: 500px; /* fixed width under 700px */ }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to this question but for anyone wondering, now you can!

Say you want to have a background image take up 100% height of parent but also have a minimum height of 200px (e.g. in case parent height is less than 200px).

We can use [max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) to get the maximum value from two numbers so if 100% height > 200px it will use 100% but if not it will stop at 200px effectively making 200px the minimum height.

```css
body {
  background-size: 100% calc(max(200px, 100%));
}
```