# Stop scaling background relatively at a certain value?

Tags: css

Apologies if the title is hard to follow.

Essentially I want the background image to scale relative to the screen size, but only above a certain point, so if you shrink the screen small enough, the image will not shrink with it.

I've done it with my divs with this:

```
.row{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 70px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

Is there something similar I can do with the background?

This is what I have at the moment.

```
.body{
    background-image: url('../static/banner.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does CSS3 offer a "minimum-size" property for "background"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682765/does-css3-offer-a-minimum-size-property-for-background)

Comment: @Phiter I've seen that post and tried the solutions but its not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please add your html markup and describe what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can do this for you, just use a breakpoint where the background has stops to scale.

> For example, this CSS will apply styles only if your browser's
>   viewport width is equal to or narrower than 12450px:
>
> ```
> @media (max-width: 12450px) { ... }
> ```

Take a look at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: please add a few more details from you link to the answer. Once the link is broken, your answer will be as well